# How to plot variable arrowheads AND variable colors?

Tags: gnuplot

Is there any way to have variable arrowheads AND variable colors?

I know that I can define different arrowstyle with different heads.
However, if I am using variable arrowstyle I cannot set a variable color.
I will get an error:

> duplicated or contradicting arguments in plot options

Apparently, e.g. an additional `lc rgb 0x123456` can't overwrite the selected arrowstyle properties? Too bad.
So, would this mean I have to define arrowstyles for all combinations of possible arrowheads and all possible colors in advance?
Alternatively, if I use only 4 different arrowheads, I could split the arrowheads into 4 separate plot elements (with many different colors).
Are there better solutions which I don't see? I tried with gnuplot 5.5.

**Script:**

```
### how to plot variable arrowheads AND variable colors?
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 1   -1    0x000000
 2    0    0xff0000
 3    1    0x00ff00
 4    2    0x0000ff
 5    1    0xff00ff
 6    2    0xffff00
 6    2    0x00ffff
EOD

set style arrow 1 backhead lw 3   # -1
set style arrow 2 nohead   lw 3   #  0
set style arrow 3 head     lw 3   #  1
set style arrow 4 heads    lw 3   #  2

set key noautotitle
set offset 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5

set multiplot layout 1,3

    set title "variable arrowstyle"
    plot $Data u (0):1:(2):(0):($2+2) w vectors as var

    set title "variable color"
    plot $Data u (0):1:(2):(0):3 w vectors lc rgb var lw 3
    
    set title "variable arrowhead and color???"
    plot $Data u (0):1:(2):(0):3 w vectors nohead lc "black" lw 1 dt 3
    
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You come up with such great corner cases! I love it.
The intended way to do this is to set `lc rgb variable` or `lc variable` in the arrow style itself.

```
set style arrow 1 backhead lw 3 lc rgb variable
set style arrow 2 nohead   lw 3 lc rgb variable
set style arrow 3 head     lw 3 lc rgb variable
set style arrow 4 heads    lw 3 lc rgb variable

set title "variable arrowhead and color"
plot $Data u (0):1:(2):(0):($0+1):3 w vectors as variable
```

I say "*the intended way*" because it turns out this doesn't quite work in practice. It requires 6 columns in the `using` specifier: `x y dx dy arrowstyle rgbcolor` but the program thinks that the maximum possible for this plot style is 5 and gives an error message `Too many using specs for this style`.

That should be an easy fix, so look for an update to the development version soonish.

**Update (21 May 2022)**

Now fixed upstream. This code will work in release 5.4.4.

Comment: Thank you for maintaining and developing gnuplot! Interesting, I'm looking forward to the update. A related question would be if linewidth could be made variable as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution which I mentioned in the question. Basically, it plots the data four times for 4 different arrowheads and each time blanking the data for the other arrowheads by using the ternary operator and `NaN`.

Maybe there are better solutions?

**Script:**

```
### plotting variable arrowheads AND variable colors
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 1   -1    0x000000
 2    0    0xff0000
 3    1    0x00ff00
 4    2    0x0000ff
 5    1    0xff00ff
 6    2    0xffff00
 6    2    0x00ffff
EOD

set style arrow 1 backhead lw 3   # -1
set style arrow 2 nohead   lw 3   #  0
set style arrow 3 head     lw 3   #  1
set style arrow 4 heads    lw 3   #  2
set key noautotitle
set offset 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5

set multiplot layout 1,3
    set title "variable arrowstyle"
    plot $Data u (0):1:(2):(0):($2+2) w vectors as var

    set title "variable color"
    plot $Data u (0):1:(2):(0):3 w vectors lc rgb var lw 3
    
    set title "variable arrowhead and color"
    plot $Data u (0):1:(2):($2==-1?0:NaN):3 w vectors lc rgb var lw 2 backhead, \
            '' u (0):1:(2):($2== 0?0:NaN):3 w vectors lc rgb var lw 2 nohead, \
            '' u (0):1:(2):($2== 1?0:NaN):3 w vectors lc rgb var lw 2 head, \
            '' u (0):1:(2):($2== 2?0:NaN):3 w vectors lc rgb var lw 2 heads
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]